# Show only the products of the selected category and not all the subcategorie products

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1.9 includes all the products of the selected category and all the subcategories in the product list on the frontend.

I have configurable products in the main category and all the simple products in subcategories.

It is important for SEO that only the selected category products are shown to be indexed by Google.

Therefore I only want the products listed in the selected category.

I have searched this forum and others but I couldn't find a solution.
In the file **`catalog/product/list.phtml`** the method getLoadedProductCollection is used to get the product collection.

How can I change the collection to get the desired effect so that only the products in the selected category are returned?

Answer (score 1):

**Go to Catalog > Manage Categories > Set Is Anchor "No"**

If you want to have all products on top categories this is option for you. Or if parent categories don't have products, only have children categories with there products than you can use this option.

You can easy enable this option, only you need to load category from Catalog => Manage Categories. Then click on second tab "Display Settings" and then change "Is Anchor" from "No" to "Yes". After that click on "Save Category" button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome  to MSE,

As per as, my knowledge,

1. **you donot need to add all configurable product's simple products** from sub categories.
2. Make all configurable product's simple products  **visibility** to
   **Not Visible Individually** .